# Move file and rename with Date and Time Stamp using a batch file

Tags: datetime, batch-file, cmd, automation, file-management

I'm using below script to move file of any name from one place and rename it in a same time to File and date stamp.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" rem & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

echo copying file
move "\\server\folder\*.*" "\\server2\folder2\File %YYYY%%MM%%DD%.pdf"  >nul
echo done
```

I would like to add a TIME (HH MM SS) to the file name too, so it would be File20170928104330.pdf However, I cannot figure out how. 
Could you please advise?

Comment: Use a FOR command to iterate the files you need to move.  That way you can manipulate the new file name.

Comment: well, i'm using it, but I'm missing the part with time (hours, minutes, seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by using powershell to get the time stamp as below:

```
    @echo off
    for /f %%a in ('powershell -Command "Get-Date -format yyyy_MM_dd__HH_mm_ss"') do set datetime=%%a

echo copying file

    move "\\server\folder\*.*" "\\server2\folder2\File-%datetime%"
echo done
```